# Testing slack bot with admin scopes in free plan

Tags: slack-api, slack-bot

I have created a Slack bot with create and delete user features and want to test it but I'm not able to do it in a free account. So I want to know if can I test it in a standard plan or if only I need an enterprise grid account. Thank you in advance.

I have tried my bot without admin scopes it is working fine but when I added it to the admin scope it is saying that you need an enterprise grid workspace for this bot.